# Spark - Maintaing order of data across columns during groupby and collect

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

If I have

```
ID  Name     Code    Value
1   Person1  A       12
1   Person2  B       15
```

And I do a

```
df.groupBy("ID").agg(
collect_set("Name").alias("Name"),
collect_set("Code").alias("Code"),
collect_set("Value").alias("Value")
)
```

I might get a

`1, [Person1, Person2], [B,A], [15,12]`

I need to get a

`1, [Person1, Person2], [A,B], [12,15]`

How do I ensure the same order for all columns ?

My actual df has 70 columns, I need to group by one columns and pick the first 5 unique values for each column in the correct order

Any suggestions are deeply appreciated

Comment: I doubt this is possible, but obviously using `collect_set` would be wrong anyways, given that it#s not a sorted set and even then the sorting would happen on the natural order of the elements in the set but not what you see in the dataframe. did you try `collect_list`? Or a custom aggregate based on e.g. LinkedHashSet?

Comment: Use `arrays_sort(collect_list(column))`

Comment: @SomeshwarKale this does not really help, if each set is sorted individually, the correspondence between them is lost

Comment: Can I ask for the use case? Maybe there might be a better approach.

Comment: @SašaZejnilović I have a df with 70 columns. I need to group by one column and pick the first 5 unique values for each other columns. And I need to make sure all columns are in the same order.

Comment: @Ajay Sangamithran,  please update your question with reqs you mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Could you leverage `monotonically_increasing_id` and pair it with each of the elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot be sure about the order in your sets, I would suggest to pack the attributes in a struct, this will give you 1 array instead of 3.

```
df.groupBy("ID").agg(
  collect_list(struct("Name","Code","Value").as("Attribute")).as("Attributes")
)
```

Comment: This logic looks good. The reason I was using collect_set was to pull in only the unique values. How do I modify this to get unique values ?

Answer (score 0):

Sets do not preserve the order. But you could trick the resulting array after `collect_list` by using some `satellite data`.

You could prepend `Person` name to the attributes as below:

```
val df2 = df.map(each => {
      val person = each.getString(1)
     (each.getInt(0), person + "|" + each.getString(1), person + "|" + each.getString(2), person + "|" + each.getInt(3))
     }).toDF("ID","Name","Code","Value")
```

Now, you could use `sort_array` after the `collect_list`, and it will sort all attributes as per `Name` of the person

```
val df3 = df2.groupBy("ID").agg( 
sort_array(collect_set("Name")).alias("Name"),
sort_array(collect_set("Code")).alias("Code"),
sort_array(collect_set("Value")).alias("Value"))
```

Note that each attribute has the person info attached in the resulting list.

```
df3.show
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| ID|                Name|                Code|               Value|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1|[Person1|Person1,...|[Person1|A, Perso...|[Person1|12, Pers...|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```